# Firebase and Swift limit post number error

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to limit the amount of posts I'm fetching to 4 but for some reason unknown to me it returns more than the limited to 4 posts without any of the data inside of the cells. But if remove the `.queryLimited(toLast: 4)` query at the end it works perfectly but loads all the posts. What am I doing wrong?

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation

    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

    let lat = userLocation.coordinate.latitude
    let lon = userLocation.coordinate.longitude

    let loc1: CLLocationDegrees = lat
    let loc2: CLLocationDegrees = lon
    let myLocation: CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: loc1, longitude: loc2)

    let myQuery = geoFire?.query(at: myLocation, withRadius: 100)

    var queryHandler = myQuery?.observe(.keyEntered, with: { (key:String!, location:CLLocation!) in

        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(key).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

            let postId = snapshot.key
            self.fetchPosts(with: postId)
            self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        })
    })
}

fileprivate func fetchPosts(with postId: String) {
    self.collectionView?.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()

    guard let currentUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

    //inital data pull
    if currentKey == nil {

        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(postId).queryLimited(toLast: 4)
        ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

            guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

            guard let uid = dict["uid"] as? String else { return }

            Database.fetchUserWithUID(uid: uid, completion: { (user) in
                guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

                var post = Post(postId: snapshot.key, user: user, dictionary: dictionary)

                let postId = snapshot.key
                post.id = snapshot.key

                self.posts.append(post)

                self.posts.sort(by: { (post1, post2) -> Bool in
                    return post1.creationDate.compare(post2.creationDate) == .orderedDescending
                })
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            })
        })
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but it looks confusing that you use ".child(postId)". It looks like you get only one post by ID.. Try: let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts").queryLimited(toLast: 4)

Comment: @SeanStayn I'm using the `postId` because I'm trying to filter the posts by location and I don't want load all of the posts just the specific ones within the radius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the line

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(postId).queryLimited(toLast: 4)
```

takes the last 4 children under postId.

If you only want 4 posts, you could try moving .queryLimited(toLast: 4) to the end of this reference where you first query "posts":

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(key)
```